# Проблема загрузки фото на стену группы с помощью vk_api

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Столкнулся с проблемой загрузки фото на стену сообщества с использованием vk_api от python273.

Пытаюсь использовать метод upload (https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html) с параметром photo_wall:

```
upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)

photo_wall = upload.photo_wall(r'путь к файлу', group_id = 'номер_группы')
```

Возвращается массив, в котором owner_id всегда указан номер пользователя, а не группы, хотя в upload.photo_wall указывал группу.

Я что-то делаю не так?

И далее:

```
owner_id = 'пишем с минусом номер группы'
media_id = str(photo_wall[0]['id'])  # берем номер из массива полученного
attachments = 'photo' + owner_id + '_' + media_id

vk.wall.post(owner_id = owner_id, from_group = 1, attachments = attachments)
```

В итоге, если в owner_id прописать номер пользователя - фото публикуется на стене пользователя то, которое было указано в пути.

Если же указать номер группы (что и требуется - опубликовать в группе) - на стене в группе публикуется совершенно рандомная фотка.

Откуда она берется, понятия не имею.

После каждого выполнения кода - фотка каждый раз разная  ^_^

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем дело?

#

В общем, в итоге я сделал так:

```
import requests
import json

# Токен бессрочный с правами wall, market и photos


token = "сюда копируем токен"
application_id = данные из ВК
group_id = номер группы, куда постить будем
owner_id_group = тоже самое, но со знаком минус. 

def write_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

def get_upload_server():
    y = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer", 
                     params={'access_token': token,'group_id': group_id, 
                             'v':"5.52"}).json()   

    return y['response']['upload_url']    #из ответа ВК забираем только 
                                          #данные в поле "upload_url"


def main():
# берем URL полученный от ВК и сохраняем его в переменную
    upload_url = get_upload_server()      

# подготавливаем файл джипег для передачи на сервер    
    file = {'photo': open('BN-301.jpg', 'rb')}          

# отправляем ПОСТ запрос на сервер с нашим файлом из переменной file    
    ur = requests.post(upload_url, files=file).json()   

# пишем полученный ответ json объект в словарь    
    write_json(ur, 'upload_photos.json')                

    photo_saved = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto', params={'access_token': token,
                                                                                     'group_id': group_id,
                                                                                     'photo': ur['photo'],
                                                                                     'server': ur['server'],
                                                                                     'hash': ur['hash'],
                                                                                     'v':"5.52"}).json() 

    write_json(photo_saved, 'upload_photos_result.json')

    attachments = 'photo' + str(photo_saved["response"][0]['owner_id']) + '_' + str(photo_saved["response"][0]['id'])

    result = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', params={'access_token': token,
                                                                    'owner_id': owner_id_group,
                                                                    'from_group': 1,
                                                                    'message': "Магия!",
                                                                    'attachments': attachments,
                                                                    'signed': 0,
                                                                    'v':"5.52"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Спасибо видосу с ютуба.

Comment: Интересно, а если этот код использовать https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/vk_api__examples/simple_wall.post_local_image/main.py ? Только в owner_id указав Id группы для `vk_session.method("wall.post"`

Comment: @gil9red, Спасибо, попробую, что получится - отпишусь

Comment: А вообще я сделал вот так:

Comment: В общем, решили руками написать общение с API? Пробовали мой пример?

Comment: @gil9red, да, мне понятнее было написать самому, чем ковырять vk_api.
пример еще не попробовал, некогда было